# Starting Homebrew service in Ansible not working

Tags: macos, jenkins, ansible, homebrew

I'm new to Ansible and i'm using it to install Jenkins CI on a Mac. Installation was not a Problem but i can't figure out how to start Jenkins via homebrew services through Ansible. It's working when i connect to the remote Mac via ssh and just run `brew services start jenkins` but when i try to just run this command via Ansible i get an error saying this:

`fatal: [Remote Mac IP]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "brew services start jenkins", "failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}`. Could not find anything like this in the web so i hope you can help me out here. My Ansible-task looks like this:

```
- name: Start Jenkins (Darwin)
  command: brew services start jenkins
  when: ansible_os_family == "Darwin"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`brew` is installed in `/usr/local/bin/` by default (and this path is likely added in `.bash_profile` which is not sourced by non-interactive shell), so add the full path to the executable:

```
- name: Start Jenkins (Darwin)
  command: /usr/local/bin/brew services start jenkins
  when: ansible_os_family == "Darwin"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked just fine. Now i get another error from Homebrew/launchctl but that's not connected to Ansible as it also shows up on manual execution.

Answer (score 0):

"...`brew` is installed in `/usr/local/bin/` by default..." - not anymore. It uses `/opt/homebrew/bin` by default now, but I have some older hardware with brew installed in `/usr/local/bin`.

Thus:

```yaml
- name: Start Jenkins (Darwin)
  ansible.builtin.command: brew services start jenkins
  environment:
    PATH: "/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
  when: ansible_os_family == "Darwin"
  become: false
```